# traitsui Range() fatal error with slider entry box

Tags: slider, mayavi, traitsui

Below is some sample code straight from the MayaVI website on using sliders. Try putting in a number outside of the slider range for a **fatal error**:

```
from numpy import arange, pi, cos, sin

from traits.api import HasTraits, Range, Instance, \
        on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item, Group

from mayavi.core.api import PipelineBase
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, SceneEditor, \
                MlabSceneModel


dphi = pi/1000.
phi = arange(0.0, 2*pi + 0.5*dphi, dphi, 'd')

def curve(n_mer, n_long):
    mu = phi*n_mer
    x = cos(mu) * (1 + cos(n_long * mu/n_mer)*0.5)
    y = sin(mu) * (1 + cos(n_long * mu/n_mer)*0.5)
    z = 0.5 * sin(n_long*mu/n_mer)
    t = sin(mu)
    return x, y, z, t


class MyModel(HasTraits):
    n_meridional    = Range(0, 30, 6, )#mode='spinner')
    n_longitudinal  = Range(0, 30, 11, )#mode='spinner')

    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    plot = Instance(PipelineBase)


    # When the scene is activated, or when the parameters are changed, we
    # update the plot.
    @on_trait_change('n_meridional,n_longitudinal,scene.activated')
    def update_plot(self):
        x, y, z, t = curve(self.n_meridional, self.n_longitudinal)
        if self.plot is None:
             self.plot = self.scene.mlab.plot3d(x, y, z, t,
                                tube_radius=0.025, colormap='Spectral')
        else:
            self.plot.mlab_source.set(x=x, y=y, z=z, scalars=t)


    # The layout of the dialog created
    view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                     height=250, width=300, show_label=False),
                Group(
                        '_', 'n_meridional', 'n_longitudinal',
                     ),
                resizable=True,
                )

my_model = MyModel()
my_model.configure_traits()
```

How can I improve this code to disallow users from triggering this fatal error? I think a line that could deactivate the entry box (such as `setDisabled(True)`) could work, or remove it entirely - but I'm not sure how to implement it within the traitsui methods.

Comment: @TobySpeight I've added the code showcasing the fatal error, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, this appears to be a bug in the default `Range()` mode of Traitsui, at least in the case for Mac OS X (I'm running High Sierra, 10.13.3).

The solution is to alter the default `mode` to one that looks and acts identical, minus crashing the program:

`n_meridional = Range(0, 30, 6, mode='slider')`